# Measure of association for two variables accounting for absolute values and relative difference

Tags: r, correlation, references, cross-correlation, association-measure

**Setting.** Two different individual characteristics, $X$ and $Y$, are measured for a subject repeatedly in time. Both variables are assumed to be continuous and non-negative.

I'm looking for a measure of association between $X$ and $Y$ that will

1. account for their absolute measured values,
2. account for relative change in their difference across the measurements,
3. take values in $[-1; 1]$ or in $(-1; 1)$ to enable comparison with various correlation coefficients, like Pearson's $\rho$ or Kendall's $\tau$.

**Sample data.** Paired measurements are made at discrete time points:
namely, for $i$-th subject in a sample we have $n_i$ measurements $X(t_{ij})$ made at time points $t_{ij},\,j=1,...,n_i$, and $n_i$ measurements $Y(t_{ij})$ made at exactly the same time points. Here are some dummy records for five subjects A to E and the corresponding time profiles for $X$ and $Y$:

```
DF = data.frame("Subject" = c(rep("A",13), rep("B",10), rep("C",5), rep("D",8), rep("E",4)),
                 "Time" = c(1, 45, 87, 127, 170, 213, 254, 302, 340, 382, 424, 466, 508,
                            1, 56, 99, 137, 183, 225, 267, 309, 350, 392,  
                            1, 48, 90, 132, 177,   
                            1, 56, 98, 140, 181, 223, 265, 307,
                            1, 56, 98, 140),
                 "X" = c(101.0, 101.0, 97.0, 97.0, 91.0, 85.0, 85.0, 84.0, 84.0,  84.0, 86.0, 87.0, 99.0,
                         76.3,  67.0,  56.0, 47.0, 37.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  
                         28.0,  31.0,  31.0, 31.0, 27.0, 
                         31.0,  24.0,  21.0, 22.0, 21.0, 21.0, 20.0, 27.0,
                         98.0,  51.0,  42.0, 35.0),
                 "Y" = c(34.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 32.0, 28.0, 28.0, 29.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 35.0, 35.0, 
                         20.6, 12.0, 16.0, 11.0, 11.7, 11.3, 10.5, 10.8, 0.0,  0.0, 
                         25.0, 21.0, 23.0, 25.0, 26.0, 
                         15.0, 14.0, 15.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 15.0, 16.0, 
                         36.0, 21.0, 15.0, 13.0),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

[image: Sample measurements profiles]

**Desired properties.** In a perfect world, the measure of association (or, more accurately, of agreement) will be:

1. positive for A, C, D, and E and negative for B,
2. greater for D than for A because the absolute difference $X-Y$ is generally smaller for D,
3. greater for A than for E because the relative difference $(X-Y)/(X_1 - Y_1)$ is changing stronger for E,
4. reasonably close to $1$ for C (while Pearson correlation coefficient is actually negative in this particular case).

Any reference, hint or idea of concept will be much appreciated.

**COMMENT.** I'm aware of how [Concordance Correlation Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient) works, but it's hard for me to interpret the effect of time distance between the two paired measurements when I use it.